# Reading various forms of data from a file and storing them in a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I didn't see anything quite like this so I decided to ask my own. I'm trying to write a program for a class of mine where you read in a set of data about grocery items from a file and you store it in a stack.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read in all of the different data types.

The data is formatted:

> (String)Produce, (String) Type, (String) Sold By [quantity], (float) price, (int) In Stock [quantity].

How could I go about reading in these different data types and saving them into my produce item structure.

```
struct produce_Item
{
   char produce[20];
   char type[20];
   char sold_By[20];
   float price;
   int quantity_In_Stock;
   struct produce_Item *next;
 }
```

Comment: thanks @nomistic, i've lurked a bit here before but this is my first post; I'm still learning the ropes :P

Comment: As with many things there are multiple ways to do what you want. One example is to use [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to read and parse the file at the same time.

Comment: @Alanau so I would have to just manually read each portion bit by bit.  Like do an fscanf and store it in produce_Item.whateverfield. Then go to the next part and repeat until EOF? Is there another, more efficient way perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Though you can pass the field pointers directly to fscanf so it's a single read (not a read and copy). Why do you think that is inefficient? It takes one pass through the file. That would seem like the minimum required. Or are you really asking whether there is a *simpler* "read and parse this file all in one go" API (note: simpler not more efficient)? The answer to the latter is that there is no standard C API for that (AFAIK).

Comment: @AlanAu yes, I misspoke; simpler was what I intended. I'm not sure I understand what you mean passing the field pointers.  Would you be passing it in the fscanf as an argument? I understand what you mean by the field pointers, the different parts of the produce_Item but I can't quite visualize what you mean by it in code form.  Do you maybe know of another question on here relating to that because google didn't quite help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical method to read a link list is to create a temporary head node and use only its `.next` field.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

  ...
  struct produce_Item Head;
  struct produce_Item *p = &Head;
  p->next = NULL;
```

Then loop through the file.  Although it is another step, things are much easier if the input is done by first reading a line with `fgets()`.  Then parse the line with `sscanf()` or `strtok()`, `strtol()`, etc. as needed.  Once the scanning completes successfully, allocate memory for a new node, save the data in it and advance `p`.

```
  FILE *file;
  char buf[100];
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) != NULL) {
    struct produce_Item Item;
    if (5 != sscanf(buf, "%19s ,%19s ,%19s ,%f ,%d", Item.produce, Item.type,
          Item.sold_By, &Item.price, &Item.quantity_In_Stock)) Handle_BadData();
    Item.next = NULL;
    // At this point, all 6 fields are set.

    struct produce_Item *Next = malloc(sizeof *Next);
    if (Next == NULL) Handle_OOM();  // Out of memory
    *Next = Item; // Copy Item to *Next

    // Advance p
    // Notice that the first time this executes, it set Head.next
    p->next = Next;
    p = Next; 
  }

  return Head.next; // The head of the list
```

Comment: so you're saying to take in the line, use strtok to separate the parts and store them into the various sections there with sscanf? I read the tutorialpoint article about strtol but im not quite sure how the base value there works.

Comment: @learning_this_now Not saying to use `strtok()` and then `sscanf()`.  As this code suggests, use `strtok()` _or_  `sscanf()` _or_ whatever parsing functions needed _or_ any combination of them to interpret the line.  This code just uses `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct produce_Item *list, **newItem = &list;
do
  *newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct produce_Item));
while (*newItem != NULL &&
       5 == fscanf(file, "%19s,%19s,%19s,%f,%d",
                         (*newItem)->produce,
                         (*newItem)->type,
                         (*newItem)->sold_By,
                         &(*newItem)->price,
                         &(*newItem)->quantity_In_Stock)
       && (newItem = &(*newItem)->next));
free(*newItem);
*newItem = NULL;
```

Note that this doesn't handle errors like too long descriptions, descriptions containing spaces or data errors. But if the data is garantied to be in order, this should work, if i haven't made a mistake.

EDIT. It didn't handle out of memory either. Otherwise this is the same as chuxs answer, just a little harder to read:)

Comment: Code does not set `(*newItem)->next`.

Comment: @chux It does set (*newItem)->next (in arguably a less common way). `newItem` is set to point to the next pointer. The body of the `do` loop will thus write a pointer value into `next` from the `malloc` result. Took me a few minutes to wrap my head around that one too.

Comment: @chux So how can you adjust it to make it assign each of the fields and then move on to the next? Also confused with the 5, is the fscanf going to return an int value of 5 because of the fields?

Comment: @learning_this_now Please read the man page for [fscanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to understand what it returns. And the above code does fill in a new product item for each input line. At the end of the code `list` will contain a linked list of each of the products. Though IMHO the code uses techniques which are a bit too advanced for illustrating the principles at a beginner level.

Comment: @Alan Au The `next` field is only used on the RHS.  It is not set even by `malloc()`.

Comment: @chux `newItem = &(*newItem)->next` That sets `newItem` to point to `next`. Then, `*newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct produce_Item));` that sets the `next` pointer.

Comment: @alanau i tried using this method and its throwing an error "request for member next is something not in struct or union"

Comment: @learning_this_now Please start a new question if you really want to get that issue solved. Can not help you from a description of code. The exact code needs to be shown otherwise it's impossible to say what the problem is (e.g. you may think you have transcribed the example correctly but perhaps not).

Comment: @Alan Au Agree `newItem = &(*newItem)->next` sets `newItem` to point to `next`.  That is not the issue - I was not commenting about `newItem` being set or not.  The `.next` field is never set nor initialized.

Comment: @chux *newItem IS next. It gets initialized with malloc.

Comment: @Mikkel Christiansen  `struct produce_Item` has 6 fields: `produce`, `type`, `sold_By`, `price`, `quantity_In_Stock` and `next`. The `fscanf()` function initializes the first 5. The 6th field called `.next` is never set anywhere in code.  Yet code reads `.next` _field_ with `newItem = &(*newItem)->next`.  What value do you think `newItem` becomes with uninitialized data?